# A 5V @ 1A wifi surveillance camera placed 50ft away (indoor)

Tags: usb, gauge

I need to place a Wifi surveillance camera near the entrance of my house where no power outlet is in that area.

I pulled a wire wrapping wire (awg 30) to the target location without thinking about wire resistance.  And as you all expected, it didn't able to power the webcam.

The power the camera uses is 5V @ 1A.

I measured the wire resistance of my awg 30 wire to the location is 11 ohms (to and from) which is 6 ohms one way which is around 50 ft.

So my question is what is the minimum gauge I need to use to be able to power my webcam placed 50ft away from the USB power adapter?

Or how many awg30 wires I need to pull to lower the resistance to allow enough power to pass through?

I assume the common practice is that the voltage drop is less than 5% of the required voltage.

So 5% of 5V is 0.25V

R=V/I so to allow 1A to pass through the resistance should be 0.25V/1A = 0.25ohms.

From the chart:
https://www.cirris.com/learning-center/calculators/133-wire-resistance-calculator-table?

Therefore I need a minimum of one 14 Gauge wire (or a bundle of fifty awg 30 wires LOL) to power the webcam 50ft way?

Comment: Are you also planning to use USB signals over that distance? I believe the maximum length advised without repeater is 30ft or such (around 10m from memory?). Just wanted to mention it.

Comment: it's a wifi webcam, so I just need power to get through.

Comment: Please don’t sprinkle vital information such as WiFi in the comments, edit your original question. If you only need 5 V and no data, there is no lack of options. Get yourself a buck converter, I’m thinking a 12-24 V cigarette plug car USB charging thing and run 24 V to it. You should be able to get away with very thinn cable.

Comment: Sorry from the missing info, I fixed my question now.   I have a buck converter already.  This is what I have.  https://www.ebay.com/p/Xl4015-5a-Dc-dc-Step-Down-Adjustable-Power-Supply-Module-Buck-Converter/1361451801?iid=332502704887&_trkparms=aid%3D555018%26algo%3DPL.SIM%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D50074%26meid%3D3637365ba7db4d1f90965987d90b120f%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D112237134540%26itm%3D332502704887&_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851

Comment: However, I connected a 12V power source and measured the current at the input of the converter is same as the current at output.  So the wire resistance will still create a problem for me?

Comment: I do have a laptop power supply lying around.  I have a buck converter, and I have 1000ft of AWG 30 wires.  I do hope not need to buy more wires.  Cuz I am in Canada and the most affordable wires are the ones from Ebay coming from China which takes 3 months to arrive.

Comment: 11 ohm is just about the “sweet spot” where your input and output currents are the same. Is it working and can you spare the ~6 W wasted in the wire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this

1) Use thick enough wire to run 5v

2) Accept a voltage drop and work round it, with easy-to-obtain parts

**Run 5V**

How much current does your webcam use? It may say '5v 1A' on the side, but have you measured it? It's probably less. But let's assume worst case of 1A.

How much voltage can you allow to drop to the camera? Let's guess at 0.5v, as 10% of your supply voltage. That may be too much, but let's do the sums for that as a baseline.

Dropping 0.5v at 1A requires a loop resistance of 0.5ohms or less. As your measured loop resistance is 11 ohms, you need 22 strands in parallel.

It would be more sensible simply to use thicker wire.

[pause] You've just updated your OP to reflect the above calculation, with slightly different starting assumptions, but the same general conclusions[/pause]

**Work with the voltage drop**

Your camera requires 5 watts. To deliver 5W into 11 ohms requires 7.5V. So a bit more than 15v supply at the house driving an 11 ohm loop and a voltage converter at the far end would be able to do the job.

Laptop adaptors (typical voltages around 19v) are easy to come by these days. You would need a buck converter at the far end, which are also easily and cheaply available, with an input range that covered at least 7 to 19v, and an output of 1A.

**Choice**

The cost and hassle of buying and drawing thicker wire, versus the cost and hassle of leaving the existing wire there, changing the driving power supply, and buying a remote voltage converter.

Notes. It's probably wise to increase the wire gauge further for option 1, as your 5v supply might be on the low side of 5v, and the camera a bit touchy about whether it gets 5.0 or 4.9v. An extra 0.25 or 0.5v drop could be the difference between it working or not.

Comment: I do have a laptop power supply lying around.  I have a buck converter, and I have 1000ft of AWG 30 wires.  I do hope I don't need to buy more wires.  Cuz I am in Canada and the most affordable wires are the ones from Ebay which come from China which take around 3 months to arrive.

Comment: Got it working!  Using my existing wires and a buck converter did the trick.  Well I actually double up the wires just to bring down the loop resistance to 6ohms to make it more efficient.  I had a hard time due to the fact I was using two different cellphones and an Ampere app to test the current.  But it doesn't charge cellphones at all for some reason.  So that kinda thrown me off for a while until I connect the buck converter to a battery.  I then connected to my surveillance camera and it worked.  The maximum current drawn on the input side of the buck is 400mA

Comment: The input voltage is 19.5v and the output is 5v. So I assume the output current of the buck would just be a little less than 4 x the input current assume the power going in is roughly the power coming out? So the maximum current on the output is 1.6A while the camera is panning.  Nominal current on the input side is 150mA.  So the power waste in delivery is 0.15A^2 * 6ohms = 0.135W? We pay ~10cents per 1kWh in Vancouver.  So that's 0.135 / 1000 * 365 * 24 * 10 = $0.12 per year wasted in delivery if my calculations are correct.

Comment: I've not checked your arithmetic, but the numbers sound plausible. Compare that cost with the cost of the power consumed by the camera itself, the power used in the laptop supply and buck, that used in whatever is receiving the pictures, and the WiFi AP/router. What you've discovered is why nationwide power delivery is done at very high voltage, and why 'point of use' switching regulators are very popular.

Comment: I felt I just learnt a very valuable lesson.  Thanks Neil.  I always thought AC was the answer for long distance electricity transmission.

Comment: AC was the answer, when 'big iron' transformers were the only economical game in town for changing voltage. Now that fast FETs make DC-DC converters affordable and efficient, a DC link is as good, and for really long distance stuff, where a DC line can shift 2x as much power for the same peak voltage, better.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by understanding a wire capacity chart like [this](https://www.platt.com/CutSheets/Multiple/AWG%20Conductors.pdf).

[image]

[image]

Since you'd typically underrate any given wire, I'd suggest that 30 AWG not be used beyond about 100 mA. 
So you'd need 10 pairs of 30 AWG to satisfy your needs.

More likely you should be using something from 20 - 18 AWG to meet the capacity requirement.

One last comment is that running 5 V long distances is not the best. You may be better using for example a 12-15 V power supply and providing a switching regulator providing the 5 V close to the Webcam. This provides much better voltage regulation.

Comment: Thanks alot for the info.  I did thought about converting the 5V from DC-to-AC and then use an inverter to invert it back to DC.  But I guess there's no such thing eh?

Comment: I guess the best way is to use a 12-15 power supply and a regulator right at the webcam location.

Comment: If I use 18-20 AWG.  Will the resistance be too great tho?  0.8-1Ohm?

Comment: Perhaps if you are trying to use just 5 V down the line. Do you have any idea of the voltage range of your Webcam? If not then you really need to use a local 5 V regulator and higher voltage power supply.